# Creating multidimensional json array using jQuery in Chrome Console

Tags: jquery, json, google-chrome-devtools

I have a working jQuery script that will output needed fields and values from a website using Chrome's console (yes, for brevity it must be done in the console).

It works fine but due to the number of fields returned, it would be much easier to read if it could be broken up into multidimensional arrays.

Below is a shortened jQuery script that's run from the console.  It's a password protected site so unfortunately I cannot provide the webpage, but I'm hoping the following examples will be easy to follow.

Since I'm a jQuery nub, I'm not not sure what's possible when trying to merge multiple objects at the end of the script, e.g "arr.push(obj);"

Here is the working script with sample output values.

### ##Working Script##

```
var arr = []; 
jQuery('#BasicInfo > table > tbody > tr >').each(function (i, v) 
{
    var obj = {}; 
    var $this = jQuery(this);  

    // section 1
    obj.orgid = jQuery('#org').val();
    obj.userid = jQuery('#userid').val();
    obj.companyname = jQuery('#companyname').val();

    // group 1
    obj.groupname1 = jQuery('#group_1').val();
    obj.productgroupid1 = jQuery('#prodgroup_1').val();
    obj.usedflag1 = jQuery('#flag_1').val();
    obj.webaddress1 = jQuery('#webaddress_1').val();

    // group 2
    obj.groupname2 = jQuery('#group_2').val();
    obj.productgroupid2 = jQuery('#prodgroup_2').val();
    obj.usedflag2 = jQuery('#flag_2').val();
    obj.webaddress2 = jQuery('#webaddress_2').val();

    arr.push(obj);  
});  JSON.stringify(arr);
```

### JSON Output

```
[{

  "orgid":"40",
  "userid":"BrennanHuff",
  "companyname":"Prestige World Wide",

  "groupname1":"Security Services",
  "productgroupid1":"1",
  "usedflag1":"Y",
  "webaddress1":"www.santamaria.com",

  "groupname2":"Investors ?",
  "productgroupid2":"2",
  "usedflag2":"Y",
  "webaddress2":"www.PrestigeWorldWide_Wide_Wide_Wide.com"
}]
```

## Goal

What I would like to accomplish, however, is to learn a way to create a more complex JSON array using jQuery

I'm unsure how to create multiple objects(?) that then get pushed out at the end and then stringified.  I've searched but can't seem to find a way to accomplish this in the console using jQuery, mostly because I'm still new to the terminology.

Thanks to any and all the take the time to read this and provide insight and feedback - it's much appreciated.

Desired JSON Output

```
[  

"companyinfo": [{  
        "orgid":"40",
        "userid":"BrennanHuff",
        "companyname":"Prestige World Wide"
        }],

"group_1":   [{
        "groupname1":"Security Services",
        "productgroupid1":"1",
        "usedflag1":"Y",
        "webaddress1":"www.santamaria.com"
          }],

"group_2":  [{
        "groupname2":"Investors ?",
        "productgroupid2":"2",
        "usedflag2":"Y",
        "webaddress2":"www.PrestigeWorldWide_Wide_Wide_Wide.com"
        }]

]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var arr = []; // the array
var obj = {}; // the object

obj.companyinfo = [{}]; // create the header array
obj.group_1 = [{}]; // create the header array
obj.group_2 = [{}]; // create the header array

// add data
obj.companyinfo[0].orgid = "40"; 
obj.companyinfo[0].userid = "BrennanHuff";
obj.companyinfo[0].companyname = "Prestige World Wide";    
obj.group_1[0].groupname1 = "Security Services";
obj.group_1[0].productgroup1 = "1";
obj.group_1[0].usedflag1 = "Y";
obj.group_1[0].webaddress1 = "www.santamaria.com";
// continue adding here...

// if you want to add another object to the group_1 array
// then just use obj.push again pointing where you want it
// to go for example.
// Delete this if you dont want it.
//-------------------
var otherObj = {};
otherObj.groupname1b = "groupname1 b";
otherObj.something = [{}];
obj.group_1.push(otherObj);
//-------------------

// push the obj into the array
arr.push(obj);

console.log(arr);
console.log("-------------------------");
// Security Services in the group_1 array
console.log(arr[0].group_1[0].groupname1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Take a look at how I did it an I hope this is what you are looking for.
```

Comment: thank you SO much!  that was it - works perfectly and just minor changes to add the new arrays.  Can't thank you enough.  All the best.

Comment: No problem. Good luck.